# Porting from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12. Problem with immutable request

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-12

I am porting application that uses Jetty as a HTTP server from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12. I use my own handler that extends ResourceHandler and changes request. I need to change request because for some requests there is session identificator in URL, and I need to remove it from URL. I also map WOPI requests (LibreOffice) and I have to change the same query with GET method to "view document", and with POST method "save document" with proper QueryString.

In Jetty 12 I changed many things like `request.getRemoteAddr()` -> `Request.getRemoteAddr(request)` but request is immutable, so I have problems with methods:
request.setQueryParameters()
request.setMethod()
request.setHttpURI()
request.setContext()

My code that works in Jetty 11:

```
class my_jetty_handler extends ResourceHandler
    {

    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            StringBuilder fileURL = new StringBuilder(target);
            ...
            // remove session from URL and put it on env
            ProcesURLSubst(fileURL, env);
            ...
            // map WOPI query to new query with changed QueryString
            WOPIRedirectURL(baseRequest, fileURL, qs, session);
            if (qs.size() > 0)
                baseRequest.setQueryParameters(qs);

            ...
            // handle static file
                String new_path = sFileURL.toString();
                baseRequest.setMethod("GET");

                baseRequest.setHttpURI(HttpURI.build(new_path));
                baseRequest.setContext(baseRequest.getContext(), new_path);
                super.handle(new_path, baseRequest, request, response);
            ...
        } // handle
```

Do you have any idea how to make changed request in Jetty 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `Request.Wrapper` to make a new Request object with the appropriate changes for the next call to `super.handle(request, response, callback);`

Example:

```java
public class AlteredRequestHandler extends Handler.Wrapper
{
    @Override
    public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback) throws Exception
    {
        HttpURI alteredHttpURI = HttpURI.build(request.getHttpURI())
            .query("a=b");
        String alteredMethod = "COPY";
        
        Request alteredRequest = new Request.Wrapper(request)
        {
            @Override
            public HttpURI getHttpURI()
            {
                return alteredHttpURI;
            }

            @Override
            public String getMethod()
            {
                return alteredMethod;
            }
        };
        
        return super.handle(alteredRequest, response, callback);
    }
}
```

Note: the Request does not have the Context.
Only the `ContextHandler` has that (even nested `ContextHandler` is supported in Jetty 12)
You can access the current context via `ContextHandler.getCurrentContext()`

Also, don't forget to look at the Jetty 11 to Jetty 12 porting guide.

https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-migration-11-to-12

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot. Jetty support on SO is wonderful!